# Passing a long query string for window.open

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need your help...

I'm making a popup with new window and it contains a sentences like

```
<p>ABCD EFG HIJKLMNOP</p>
<br />
<p>QR S T U V?? WS YNG</p>
so on...
```

(it is in a javascript variable `var contents`)

And in my javascript I send this long string to ASP.NET Core Controller to open new window.

**JavaScript**

```
previewWindowUrl = "/Controller/Popup?strContents=" + encodeURIComponent(contents);
var myWindow = window.open(previewWindowUrl, "", "scrollbars=no,width=1000px, ...");
```

**ASP.NET Core Controller**

```
public IActionResult Popup(string strContents) 
{

    // some process for manupulating strContents        

    return View();
}
```

But, when I send too long string to Controller Action, the page show error

```
HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.
```

How can I handle it?

And is there other way to send long query string and receive it for open window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually when we make a request its consider as GET request and there is limit in get request for number of characters so for that its giving this kind of error.

so instead of passing that value in query string try to store that value  in hidden field of parent page and access that from the page that you are opening from parent page.